# Passing functions between components in React and React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to migrate a prototype I started in ReactJS to React Native. Simple enough so far until I started to migrate a context-held function on a wrapping Component. For the life of me I can't get it to call in the context of the element on which the function is defined.

Here's a boiled down version of what I'm trying to achieve:

### ReactJS

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  childContextTypes: {
    onButtonClick: React.PropTypes.func
  },
  onButtonClick: function() {
    console.log("Button pressed", this); // this is instance of Parent when done in ReactJS
  },
  getChildContext: function() {
    return {
      onButtonClick: this.onButtonClick
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (<div><Child /></div>);
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  contextTypes: {
    onButtonClick: React.PropTypes.func
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.context.onButtonClick}>Click me</button>
    ); 
  }
});
```

### React Native

```
class Parent extends Component {
  static childContextTypes = {
    onButtonClick: React.PropTypes.func
  };

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      onButtonClick: this.onButtonClick
    }
  };

  onButtonClick() {
    console.log("Button pressed", this); // this is returning `undefined`
  };

  render() {
    return (<div><Child /></div>);
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    onButtonClick: React.PropTypes.func
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.context.onButtonClick()}>
        <Text>Click Me</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

Apologies if the above is not 100% accurate (I hand-wrote it just now to make the problem clear). I'm confident the issue is to do with either my declaration of the function on the Parent Component, or the execution of it in the `onPress` event on the Child Component.

On a side note, if there's a better way of making a button click on a child component affect the wider application without passing the event up to a function on a parent component per above, then I'd love to know, it seems a bit messy to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a lot have changed during these 9 months when question was asked.

1. You should not use context https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html
2. to pass actions around Redux is most popular flex style extension and i recommend using it. http://redux.js.org/
3. i do recommend to have pure components and just to have inner state if needed and no functions passing as props between components.
4. Components composition is getting to be popular approach.

From ReactJS context documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context

> If you only want to avoid passing some props through many levels, component composition is often a simpler solution than context.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.bind(this)`, so your function will be like this:

```
getChildContext: function() {
    return {
      onButtonClick: this.onButtonClick.bind(this)
    }
```